# C# code for automating a website

Tags: c#-4.0

All I want is to record the actions I perform in a website and have to get the code generated for the same in c#.To make it clear,I juss want to run the code so that the manual activity is performed automatically.Any help would be great.Thanks a lot.

Comment: There are numerous off-the-shelf products which support this functionality.  What research have you done into this already?

Comment: I am in a corner now to automate a website.I have done some googling.But what I need it is a step by step by procedure which none of the forums have provided so far.Your help on this is duely appreciable

Comment: Have you had a look at [selinium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/)? If yes, please specify exactly why it is not going to help you.

Comment: I have heard and learnt some tutorials about Selenium.But no tutorial have provided its use in a step-by-step manner.I am a fresher and need a systematic low-level document or tutorial.Please help.

Comment: Generating C# code to replicate your HTTP requests sounds awkward way to go. It seems easier would be to find an application that can replicate your HTTP requests and run that application from within your C# program. Furthermore, I guess many web site sessins cannot be just blindly replicated (e.g. session ids contained in `POST` requests).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `Visual Studio` has [web test recording](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182539%28v=VS.80%29.aspx), it actually can generate code for you. This will record integration between browser and server. So if you rerun, server will think that you are doing something. This option is not browser automation.
2. [WatiN](http://watin.org/) is another option. This time, it is browser automation tool. It has [recording tool](http://watintestrecord.sourceforge.net/) too.
3. Third option is [Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/), very similar to WatiN. There are many tools to record Selenium scripts. Most supported one is [Selenium IDE](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/projects/ide/).

All tools, are quite easy to work with, and you can find good tutorials on the respective sites.

My best guess, of your needs is that you need #2 or #3. It looks like #3 is more active/mature tool, but I used both with success, so no problem to choose #2.

If you will go with #1, check what edition of `Visual Studio` you use. I am afraid, Web Testing could be available only in top editions, like `Ultimate`.

Comment: :Thanks a lot Mike.Now at least I have got a path to go on.Thanks for ur help.